# maven build complains about version ranges

Tags: java-8, maven-3, bamboo, nimbus-jose-jwt

We have a EAR project, which has a web project. pom.xml contains the following dependencies in addition to 100s of more dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
      <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>8.19</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
      <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
      <version>8.19</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>[2.7.1,)</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Our builds started failing recently. This is the error

```
build   28-Jul-2022 17:12:10    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project abcWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz:abcWeb:war:1.22.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:8.19 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]: No versions available for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3] within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

Similar thing happened for xalan dependency too.
If we give an exclusion for json-smart:jar under the nimbus dependencies, and add the json-smart dependency ourselves with a specific version 2.3, we can get past this issue.
This dependency was there for the past 5 years without any issues. We have not done any manual changes to bamboo, maven version or JDK version.
This appears to be happening all of a sudden. It looks like maven does not like version ranges.

We have bamboo builds. It uses **apache-maven-3.6.0**, and **JDK_1_8_0_191**.
In the development environment, this can be replicated using command line maven (maven 3.8.5, jdk 1.8.0.332). However, within Eclipse IDE with its embedded maven (and jdk1.8.0_281), we are not having this issue. In Eclipse IDE, while building, maven is pulling json-smart-2.3.jar into the project maven dependencies (class path). Eclipse IDE embedded maven version says 3.6.3/1.16.0.20210129-0849

full stack trace

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project abcWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.auto.myl:abcWeb:war:4.21.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:8.19 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]: No versions available for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3] within specified range -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project abcWeb: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.auto.myl:abcWeb:war:4.21.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:8.19 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.auto.myl:abcWeb:war:4.21.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:8.19 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:8.19 -> net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies (DefaultDependencyCollector.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve (DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:243)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.VersionRangeResolutionException: No versions available for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3] within specified range
```

Comment: The first question: Is that in an corporate environment? The issue is this: `No versions available for net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3] within specified range -> [Help 1]` If you are in a corporate environment: Are you using a repository manager? You have tested that with plain command via Maven 3.8.6... also please post the full log output ... also an example project which replicates the behaviour?...

Comment: Also an recomendation from my side. Don't use version ranges...

Comment: I think it is corporate environment. we have jFrog repository for artifactory. I confirmed that json-smart.jar versions: 2.2, 2.2.1, 2.3 and many others exist in this artifactory. I used my dev environment maven (3.8.x) against a settings.xml pointing to this jFrog repository. It gives the same error.

Comment: Ah.. sorry: `I think it is corporate environment.` you think? Hm.. what is your dev environment maven? Which version exactly.. also the settings.xml would be helpful also as I already wrote the full log output of the build...

Comment: Also, we have com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:8.19 only in our pom as a dependency. This library has its dependency on artifact net.minidev:json-smart:jar:[1.3.1,2.3]

Comment: Since it is replicated locally in the development environment, I have the following:
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\develop\apache-maven-3.8.1
Java version: 1.8.0_281, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_281\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246894/discussion-between-gsakthivel-and-khmarbaise).